# UpdateRange method of Entity Framework Core does not work

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

The `UpdateRange` method of Entity Framework Core is used here to update multiple records but it is not working.

My code is:

```
var dept1 = new Department()
{
    Id = 8,
    Name = "New Designing"
};

var dept2 = new Department()
{
    Id = 9,
    Name = "New Research"
};

var dept3 = new Department()
{
    Id = 102,
    Name = "New HR"
};

List<Department> modifiedDept = new List<Department>() { dept1, dept2, dept3 };

using (var context = new CompanyContext())
{
    context.UpdateRange(modifiedDept);
    await context.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

And the error I get is:

> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateConcurrencyException: 'Database operation expected to affect 1 row(s) but actually affected 0 row(s). Data may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=527962 for information on understanding and handling optimistic concurrency exceptions.'

What should be done in this case?

Comment: I doubt this exact code worked in any version of EF Core with the same database. The exception simply indicates that some of the provided `Id` is missing in the target table.

Comment: Or you changed the model in the mean time and now it has a concurrency token.

Comment: @IvanStoev I found the problem which is in my code. The id "102" was not there in DB so the transaction was rolled back. I think it is better to fetch the id from the db so that typing mistakes does not happen.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are supposed to get data from database and modify data. Not creating new class.

```
using (var context = new JobContext())
{
    var depts = context.Department.Where(x => x.Id > 1).AsQueryable();
    depts.Where(x => x.Id == 2).FirstOrDefault().Name = "New Designing";
    depts.Where(x => x.Id == 3).FirstOrDefault().Name = "New Research";
    depts.Where(x => x.Id == 4).FirstOrDefault().Name = "New HR";

    context.UpdateRange(depts);
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Before

[image]

After

[image]