# Can I take advantage of List<T> functions Remove(T) and Insert(Int32, T) when using UpdateRange(IEnumerable<T>)?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I am attempting to implement a controller method to reorder image indexes that need to be saved in the database using EF Core.

I have the following controller method:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<JsonResult> ReorderImage(int p_iImageID, int p_iNewOrderIndex)
{
     if (p_iImageID <= 0)
          return Json(new { Status = "Error", Message = $"Unable to retrieve item image with ID of {p_iImageID}" });

     ItemImage l_oItemImage = await _Context.ItemImages.FirstOrDefaultAsync(l_oImage => l_oImage.ID == p_iImageID);

     if (l_oItemImage.IsNull())
          return Json(new { Status = "Error", Message = $"Unable to retrieve item image with ID of {p_iImageID}" });


     List<ItemImage> l_oItemImages = await _Context.ItemImages.Where(l_oImage => l_oImage.ItemID == l_oItemImage.ItemID)
                                                              .OrderBy(l_oImage => l_oImage.Order)
                                                              .ToListAsync();

     l_oItemImages.Remove(l_oItemImage);
     l_oItemImages.Insert(p_iNewOrderIndex, l_oItemImage);

     foreach(ItemImage l_oImage in l_oItemImages)
     {
          l_oImage.Order = l_oItemImages.IndexOf(l_oImage);

          if (l_oItemImages.IndexOf(l_oImage) == 0)
               l_oImage.IsPrimary = true;
          else
               l_oImage.IsPrimary = false;

          l_oImage.Uri = _AzureBlobStorage.GetBlobUri(_ItemImageAzureBlobContainerName, l_oImage.GetFileName());
     }

     _Context.ItemImages.UpdateRange(l_oItemImages);
     await _Context.SaveChangesAsync();

     return Json(l_oItemImages)
}
```

The order and data of `l_oItemImages` when calling `UpdateRange()` and subsequently `SaveChangesAsync()` appears correct to me.

I've been looking at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63325587/updaterange-method-of-entity-framework-core-does-not-work) which mentions not creating new classes and using `UpdateRange()`. This seems a bit different but I can see how this might be my issue.

Am I having this issue because I'm manipulating the objects of the list using `Remove(l_oItemImage)` and then `Insert(p_iNewOrderIndex, l_oItemImage)`? Or is it because I'm using `ToListAsync()` to begin with when I grab the item images?

EDIT: Tried `Update(l_oItemImage)` in place of `UpdateRange(l_oItemImages)` with same results. Added image of QuickWatch showing tacked entities both are correctly showing `State = Modified` as well as the expected changed values for `int Order` and `bool IsPrimary` properties.

[image: QuickWatch for DBContext.ChangeTracker.Entries()]

EDIT 2: Added image of QuickWatch data with highlighted changed properties on entities.

[image: QuickWatch data for full entities modified.]

Comment: Could you give us a little more context? First the exact error you see, then the class definition and the object-relational mapping (relationships ecc). Without any of that I would tell you to call a `DetectChanges` (just to be sure) and `DbContext.ChangeTracker.Entries()` to inspect the entries involved. Do you really need to call `UpdateRange`? I mean, have you disabled tracking from the `DbContext` configuration?

Comment: @MarcoLuzzara I get no error. The database just simply does not update the changed entities. Tried changing to `foreach` and using `Update(l_oItemImage)` instead of using `UpdateRange(l_oItemImages)` with same results. I attached an image that shows results for `DbContext.ChangeTracker.Entries()` which shows correctly modified data of both image objects (I can screenshot full data if needed but it is as I expect). I haven't explicitly disabled tracking in the `DbContext` and other functions seem to properly update the ItemImages context so I'm at a loss here for what's going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you should be able to take advantage of the List methods however I think `UpdateRange` is unnecessary for this common task, here is an alternative implementation.

You may want to consider something like the following instead where the Sequence is reassigned for a subset of sequenced entities:

```
public async Task SetSequenceAsync(int forPageComponentId, int newSequence)
{
    var infoAboutItemWereChangingSequenceFor = await context.PageComponents
        .Where(x => x.Id == forPageComponentId)
        .Select(x => new  { 
            OriginalSequence = x.Sequence, // I need to know it's current sequence.
            x.PageId // I need to only adjust sequences for items that have the same PageId, so I need to know what the pageId is for the item we're targeting.
        }).FirstOrDefaultAsync();

    // Get just the data we want to modify, we're going to include the item we're targeting so this list is inclusive of it.
    // Including the item we're changing to make logic below a little mor consise instead of managing the list and the item we're targeting
    // seperately.
    var allItemsWithSequenceThatWillChange = await context.PageComponents
        .Where(x =>
            x.PageId == infoAboutItemWereChangingSequenceFor.PageId // Only those items sharing the same page Id.
            // Only those items we need to change the sequence for.
            && x.Sequence >= Math.Min(infoAboutItemWereChangingSequenceFor.OriginalSequence, newSequence)
            && x.Sequence <= Math.Max(infoAboutItemWereChangingSequenceFor.OriginalSequence, newSequence)
        )
        .Select(x =>
            new PageComponent() // The type of object EF knows about.
            {
                // The Primary key, so Entity Framework knows what record to change the sequence on.
                Id = x.Id,
                // The sequence value we need to change.
                Sequence = x.Sequence
            }
        ).ToListAsync();

    // Set the sequence of the item we're targeting.
    allItemsWithSequenceThatWillChange
        .Where(x => x.Id == forPageComponentId)
        .First()
        .Sequence = newSequence;

    // Now update the sequence on the other items (excluding the target item)
    foreach (var item in allItemsWithSequenceThatWillChange.Where(x => x.Id != forPageComponentId))
    {
        // Either increment or decrement the sequence depending on how the original item was moved.
        item.Sequence += infoAboutItemWereChangingSequenceFor.OriginalSequence > newSequence ? 1 : -1;
        // Add any other property changes here.
    }

    // Save changes.
    await context.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

Also, as a matter of simplification on your ItemImage object, I notice you have an apparently DB persisted property "IsPrimary" - you may want to change this to be calculated on the entity and even at the db level instead, eg:

```
public class ItemImage {
    // ... Other Properties ...
    public int Order { get; set; }
    public bool IsPrimary {
        get => Order == 0;
        set {}
    }
}
```

For a calculated column in your MSSQL Database you can query against, add to your DbContext OnModelCreating:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
{
    builder.Entity(typeof(ImageObject)).Property("IsPrimary").HasComputedColumnSql("CASE WHEN [Order] = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END");
}
```

Comment: I get an error on this line `context.AttachRange();`. The error I receive is `System.InvalidOperationException: The instance of entity type 'ForkliftImage' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'ID'} is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached. Consider using 'DbContextOptionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging' to see the conflicting key values.`

Comment: I also appreciate your suggestion to simplify the model. I agree and have added it to my backlog tasks. For the time being when I tried your answer I added the attribute to the queries and have it being set in the last `foreach()` statement.

Comment: Removing this line between my checks at the top seemed to remove the error I commented about earlier but there seems to be other issues with this code for me. `ItemImage l_oItemImage = await _Context.ItemImages.FirstOrDefaultAsync(l_oImage => l_oImage.ID == p_iImageID);`

Comment: Anytime you load an entity object from the context, it'll be tracked by default - you don't need to attach it. If you load the same entity twice, it should actually return the already loaded entity. To avoid this, either 1.) load a NEW anonymous object OR use .AsNoTracking() in your query such as context.ForkLiftImages.AsNoTracking().Where(....)...

Comment: I may have erroniously added the "context.AttachRange()" after getting the list of items to change, they may already be tracked - untested code, LOL. If that's the case, I'll update the answer. The joys of untested-code answers...

Comment: Your answer helped me realize I failed to notice a change in how my view is fed the order of images. It turns out I removed an `OrderBy()` clause when feeding the view data before the drag drop even happened. Therefore the drag and drop starting state was invalid and since my test case only had two images this was not obvious. Change your answer to remove the `AttachRange()` since that was the only thing that caused an issue and say something like "Yes, you should be able to take advantage of the List<T> methods here is an alternative implementation...". I will accept as answer.

Comment: I made the change as requested, and made this comment long enough to post! :P